# Select date with the least different (from today) from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, select

Can someone tell me how to select the most recent date (with the least different) from now?

Currently I'm using something like this

```
SELECT MAX(DatumAangemaakt) AS RecenteSchema FROM Personeelsschema
```

I use the Max() function, but it's no good because if I have a date in the future (e.g. 2015-06-23) this date will be selected.

And what I need is to select today's date (if there any) or the most recent date from today, e.g:
2015-06-23
2015-06-01
2015-05-17 (this one will be selected)
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all dates past the current date, order them and get the top record:

```
SELECT DatumAangemaakt AS RecenteSchema
FROM Personeelsschema
WHERE DATE(DatumAangemaakt) >= DATE(NOW()) 
ORDER BY  DatumAangemaakt  LIMIT 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c61b2/2)

If you also want to include *dates from the past* in your proximity check, then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT DatumAangemaakt
FROM Personeelsschema
ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DatumAangemaakt, DATE(NOW()))) LIMIT 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb2581/1)

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try this one now and let you know

Comment: This gets the dates from the future but not the past, right? If I want to get the dates from the past, should I do that? `OR DATE(DatumAangemaakt) <= DATE(NOW())`

Comment: @ElomarAdam I just made an edit that addresses this exact point!

Comment: Yes I just saw that after I wrote the comment, this solves everything! Thank you sir very much for your help! Really appreciated! ^^